# Ruby error UTF-8 to ASCII

Tags: ruby, ascii, rubygems, centos

I have a Ruby 1.9.2 install on Centos 5.5. Every time I install a gem, I get the error

```
ERROR:  While generating documentation for (gem)
... MESSAGE:   U+2018 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII
... RDOC args: lib History.txt README.txt
```

The gem still installs ok, but there are certain things I can't do. Like use SproutCore, for example. I get this little gem (pun intended).

```
sc-init xxxx
 ~ Created directory at xxxx
FATAL ~ invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on, and how to remedy it? Google isn't much help on this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RDoc updated last week, and was supposed to help fix encoding problems.

Try `gem update rdoc` and see if that helps.

Comment: No dice. I just got more errors -->
`Installing RDoc documentation for rdoc-3.5.3...
unable to convert U+201D from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/rdoc/text.rb, skipping`
unable to convert "\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for History.txt, skipping

Comment: Check your `LC_CTYPE` and `LANG` environment variables. My Mac desktop and primary CentOS 5.3 box are set to "en_US.UTF-8" for both. I see occasional messages similar to yours.

Comment: Well, I don't think it'll fix the problem entirely. Like I said, I see it occasionally, but not as bad as the previous version of RDoc.

Comment: Had this problem on a Debian system where locales had not been set up.  Had to run: `locale-gen en_US.UTF-8`.  This should also work: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

Comment: Or add these two lines to bash or zsh profile – `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` and `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`. Then restart terminal and type `locale`.

Comment: `gem update rdoc` got rid of `unable to convert "\xD0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ...` 3 years after your answer! Thanks.