# Nokogiri - unable to convert U+2019 from UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for CHANGELOG.ja.rdoc, skipping

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

With `gem install nokogiri`

I'm getting below response.

How do I fix this error?

```
Installing ri documentation for nokogiri-1.5.6...
unable to convert U+2019 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/nokogiri.rb, skipping
unable to convert "\xE3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for CHANGELOG.ja.rdoc, skipping
unable to convert "\xE8" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for CHANGELOG.rdoc, skipping
unable to convert "\xE9" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for README.ja.rdoc, skipping
unable to convert "\xE9" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for README.rdoc, skipping
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for ext/nokogiri/xml_node_set.c, skipping
Installing RDoc documentation for nokogiri-1.5.6...
unable to convert U+2019 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/nokogiri.rb, skipping
unable to convert "\xE3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for CHANGELOG.ja.rdoc, skipping
unable to convert "\xE8" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for CHANGELOG.rdoc, skipping
unable to convert "\xE9" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for README.ja.rdoc, skipping
unable to convert "\xE9" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for README.rdoc, skipping
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for ext/nokogiri/xml_node_set.c, skipping
```

Comment: This isn't an error, it's a warning. What does the documentation look like when you use `ri Nokogiri` at the command line?

Comment: I get the exact same warning, when I run ri Nokogiri I get the following message:  "Nothing known about .nokogiri"

Comment: consider the solutions at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917859/ruby-error-utf-8-to-ascii or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975973/gem-update-unable-to-convert-xe7-to-utf-8-in-conversion-from-ascii-8bit-to-u