# Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+00A0 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, nokogiri

I'm trying to scrap the 52 between the anchor links:

> ```
> <div class="zg_usedPrice">
> <a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B000O3GCFU/ref=zg_bs_baby-products_price?ie=UTF8&condition=new">52&nbsp;new</a>
> </div>
> ```

With this code:

```
 def self.parse_products
    product_hash = {}
    product = @data.css('#zg_centerListWrapper')

    product.css('.zg_itemImmersion').each do | product |
      product_name = product.css('.zg_title a').text
      product_used_price_status = product.css('.zg_usedPrice > a').text[/(\D+)/]
      product_hash[:product] ||= []
      product_hash[:product] << { :name             => product_name,
                                  :used_status      => product_used_price_status }
    end 

    product_hash
  end
```

But I think the `http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B000O3GCFU/ref=zg_bs_baby-products_price?ie=UTF8&condition=new` part in the URL is producing the following error:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError:
   U+00A0 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII
 # ./parser_spec.rb:175:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I tried what they suggested in "[Ruby error UTF-8 to ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917859/ruby-error-utf-8-to-ascii)", but I'm still getting the same problem. Is there any workaround for that?

---

Full error trace:

```
  1) Product (Baby) should return correct keys
     Failure/Error: expect(product_hash[:product]["Pet Supplies"].keys).to eq(["Birds", "Cats", "Dogs", "Fish & Aquatic Pets", "Horses", "Insects", "Reptiles & Amphibians", "Small Animals"])
     TypeError:
       can't convert String into Integer
     # ./parser_spec.rb:179:in `[]'
     # ./parser_spec.rb:179:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Product (Baby) should return correct values
     Failure/Error: expect(product_hash[:product]["Pet Supplies"].values).to eq([16281, 245512, 513926, 46811, 14805, 364, 5816, 19769])
     TypeError:
       can't convert String into Integer
     # ./parser_spec.rb:183:in `[]'
     # ./parser_spec.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Product (Baby) should return correct hash
     Failure/Error: expect(product_hash[:product]).to eq({"Pet Supplies"=>{"Birds"=>16281, "Cats"=>245512, "Dogs"=>513926, "Fish & Aquatic Pets"=>46811, "Horses"=>14805, "Insects"=>364, "Reptiles & Amphibians"=>5816, "Small Animals"=>19769}})
     Encoding::UndefinedConversionError:
       U+00A0 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII
     # ./parser_spec.rb:187:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: can you give the full error trace?

Comment: what is at line#179 and line#183 ?

Comment: @Babai line#179: `      product_hash[:product] << { :asin             => product_asin,
`

Comment: @Babai line#183 `                                  :used_status     => product_used_price_status,
`

Comment: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help us quickly find what is wrong.  How about making a standalone Ruby script that people can run on their own computers that produces the error?  Also, what versions of Ruby and Nokogiri are you using, and what OS?

Comment: Somewhere, some part of your system is getting a byte whose value is 0xA0 and trying to interpret it as US-ASCII, where all the bytes are supposed to be less than 0x80.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML sample doesn't match the code you're showing, plus the URL you gave doesn't exist any more, so it's difficult to help you.

Here's a start:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '<div class="zg_usedPrice">
    <a href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000O3GCFU">52&nbsp;new</a>
    </div>
'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

text = doc.at('div.zg_usedPrice a').text # => "52\u00A0new"
text.gsub(/\u00A0/, ' ') # => "52 new"
```