# Ruby gamebox can't find the file gosu.for_1_9.so even though it's right there

Tags: ruby, rubygems, libgosu

Preface: I'm on a Windows 8 box, running Ruby 2.0.0.

I recently installed the `gamebox` gem for Ruby. During the installation of all its dependencies, a few files, among them the file `$RUBYHOME/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/gosu-0.7.50-x86-mingw32/lib/gosu.for_1_9.so`, did not build properly because of some ASCII/Unicode issues in `rdoc`, and were thus "skipped". I hadn't payed much attention to it initially, but when I tried to run `gamebox test_game` to setup a new `gamebox` game, it spat the following message at me:

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:118:in `require': 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/gosu-0.7.50-x86-mingw32/lib/gosu.for_1_9.so (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:118:in `rescue in require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:124:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/gosu-0.7.50-x86-mingw32/lib/gosu.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:114:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:114:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/gamebox-0.5.0/lib/gamebox.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:66:in  `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:66:in  `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/gamebox-0.5.0/bin/gamebox:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/gamebox:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/gamebox:23:in `<main>'
```

The important bit there is `The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/gosu-0.7.50-x86-mingw32/lib/gosu.for_1_9.so`

I then went back and realized the whole Unicode thing, updated `rdoc` to the newest version as per [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4917996/470925), and ran `gem uninstall gosu` followed by `gem install gosu`. Everything seemed to build just fine, and I saw that the needed file, `.../gosu.for_1_9.so`, was right where it needed to be.

However, I am still getting **exactly the same error** about not being able to find `gosu.for_1_9.so`!

I've been able to find exactly two Google results where someone else had this issue. In one situation the problem was peripheral because the guy was hacking on his `gosu` installation a bit; in the other, the solution was "Ruby 2 is bad and you should use Ruby 1.9", which is really not my preferred option.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Ken,

The file is being found, but is not compatible to load in Ruby 2.0.0.

This is a bug / missing feature of Gosu. It does not work with Ruby 2.0.0 on Windows. The author of the gem has plans to work this out, but has not yet tackled it. You can follow up on the issue on Github here: https://github.com/jlnr/gosu/issues/163

The author can be found on freenode IRC in #gosu. I'm sure they could use some help with their windows support. Unfortunately, the answer to using Gamebox on Windows is to downgrade to Ruby 1.9.3. I will add this to the Gamebox wiki.

Comment: Thing is though, it *does* work in Ruby 2.0; I have it working just fine on another box.

Comment: What are the differences between this box and the one it works fine on? I have the exact same error on Windows 7 with Ruby 2.0.0.  Are they both Windows 8? are they both 32bit? same Ruby installer used? etc

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Shawn42

But probably the best way is to install beforehand a ruby version manager.

RVM with Pik is what I use on Windows.

That way you can install the older 1.9.3 version of ruby and call pik to use that version whenever you want to use gamebox. You'll still have ruby 2.0.0 installed and ready to be used for your other projects.

http://www.ruby-on-rails-outsourcing.com/articles/2010/07/28/ruby-version-manager-for-windows/

Cheers